# Is there a reference of all the user data structures used over linux (gcc)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, libc

where is the type size_t  defined what are the other types like this , **Is there a reference of the all the user defined  types and data structures in linux (gcc) .**
for example a reference guide on

- sockaddr_in6
- sockaddr_in
- mm_struct
- pci_dev
- sk_buff
- tq_struct

...

Comment: `<stddef.h>`, `ptrdiff_t`, `max_align_t`, ... And `size_t` is certainly not `unsigned int` here, nor on most 64-bit systems.

Comment: @KingsIndian: That searches every `stddef.h` file on your system; not all of them are necessarily relevant. It can also take a very long time, especially if your system mounts NFS filesystems. And it won't resolve other files included by `stddef.h>`. This works for me: `echo '#include <stddef.h>' | gcc -E - | grep size_t`

Comment: @KeithThompson Nice. That's a clever way of letting gcc do the seach for you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The definitive reference is the standard.

The C standard defines `size_t` and says it's defined in `<stddef.h>` (on GNU/Linux that header is provided by GCC) and POSIX requires it to be defined after including [`<sys/types.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html)

The POSIX standard defines `sockaddr_in6` in [`<netinet/in.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html)

> also for eg : size_t, which is typically an unsigned int , why we define > size_t val ; rather than unsigned int val ;

Because it might not be `unsigned int`. On my platform it's `unsigned long`, so by writing `size_t` you get a type guaranteed to be able to represent the necessary range of values. Using `unsigned int` doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: let me know what u mean by definitive reference

Comment: I mean exactly what the words "definitive reference" mean. The C and POSIX standards are what **define** the meaning of the `size_t` and `sockaddr_in6` types.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is something like http://www.man7.org/tlpi/